# How to use a switch structure where one case checks for arguments and another checks for no argument

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am having trouble creating a "commands help page" for a Discord bot using JavaScript.

Currently the code I have allows the user to call the command using `!help`, and I need to create a structure that uses arguments to either:

1) Call a specific page of Help Commands by comparing the argument in an `if/else` statement and sending a message to the channel of that group of commands. (example: Calling `!help utility` would bring up a list of utility commands and `!help general` would bring up the general commands list.

2) Display a default page of commands if no argument is present. (Just typing in `!help`.)

My idea is that I should use an `if/else` statement to check to see if the argument is present, however I don't know if this is the correct method of doing this, or how to even do that.

Here is some of my code that I'm trying to implement. It doesn't work, but it has the idea that I'm trying to implement.

```
switch(argument[0]) {
    case "help":

        if(! argument[1]){
            var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle("General Commands")
                .setColor([60, 215, 115])
                .setDescription("Commands used throughout the server")
                .setTimestamp()
                break;
        } else if(argument[1] == 'utility') {
            var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle("Utility Commands")
                .setColor([60, 215, 115])
                .setDescription("Commands used by moderators")
                .setTimestamp()
                break;
        }
}
```

Thank you for looking over this in advance. I appreciate any help given.

Comment: What do you mean with it doesn't work?

Comment: I meant that the `if(! argument[1]){` line didn't properly test to see whether or not an argument was being input. I posted my solution for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer. I had to test this:

```
 if(args[1] == undefined){
            var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
```

That `args[1] == undefined` means that there was no user input for the argument, and instead just takes the `!help` and displays the regular help screen.

Proof that it just takes a little research and you can figure out anything! :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I suggest you use switch inside switch:

```
switch(argument[0]) {
    case "help":
        switch(argument[1])
        {
            case undefined:
            case "general":
                var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setTitle("General Commands")
                    .setColor([60, 215, 115])
                    .setDescription("Commands used throughout the server")
                    .setTimestamp()
                break;
            case "utility":
                var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Utility Commands")
                    .setColor([60, 215, 115])
                    .setDescription("Commands used by moderators")
                    .setTimestamp()
                break;
        }
    break;
}
```

Don't forget `!help general` should also work.